# expect toHaveBeenCalledWith not working with latest CreateReactApp setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I have code like below which checks if my named function has been called with certain arguments:

```
    const wrapper = mount(<PromotionsContent {...props} />);
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('page', 0);
    params.append('size', '20');

    expect(getPromotions).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
```

Here getPromotions is a named function which is imported and mocked correctly in the test file. This used to work fine before but after upgrading my app to use latest CreateReactApp(with React 16.12.0) it has started breaking. I have also logged params to the console just before where getPromotions is called and I could actually see right values but in the test it just prints like below and fails:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    - {},
    + {},

    Number of calls: 1
```

Surprisingly if I directly use the called arguments like below it works:

```
    const wrapper = mount(<PromotionsContent {...props} />);
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('page', 0);
    params.append('size', '20');

   let calledParams = getPromotions.mock.calls[0][0];
   expect(calledParams.get('page')).toEqual ('0');
   expect(calledParams.get('size')).toEqual ('20');
```

Any clues, please?

Comment: `params.append('page', 0);` is different from `expect(calledParams.get('page')).toEqual('0');`. It's `'0'` vs. `0`. That could be the issue.

Comment: @Remolten this cant be the issue since URLSearchParams is converting all values to string (Search params can only be a string).

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on a fresh install of react app using `16.12.0` and it is working.

Can you share more of your code?

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

const MyComponent = ({ getPromotions }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("page", "0");
    params.append("size", "0");

    getPromotions(params);
  }, []);
  return null;
};

describe("Lorem Ipsum", () => {
  it("should pass", () => {
    const getPromotionsMock = jest.fn();
    render(<MyComponent getPromotions={getPromotionsMock} />);
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("page", "0");
    params.append("size", "0");

    expect(getPromotionsMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am using enzyme 'mount' actually.

Comment: @geekprogrammer I think they are similar libraries. Try replacing `render` with `mount`

Answer (score 0):

Jest will throw this error if the params are different, I think the params which you are using in the component are different then the params are used in test.

Please check the params again and if possible add the component code in the question as well.

The test result is clearly showing that the function is called but the params are not matching.

Comment: No the params in both places are correct. This test had worked fine before I upgraded.

Comment: This case happened in NodeJS, after fix params are different, my issue is fixed. Thanks!